# How can I prevent the original Page form being executed and rendered, if a Middleware redirects the user to a different Page (Razor Pages)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Let's assume the following Razor page classes:

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IndexModel() => Console.WriteLine("Index.ctor()");
    public void OnGet() => Console.WriteLine("Index.OnGet()");
}

public class Divert : PageModel
{
    public Divert() => Console.WriteLine("Divert.ctor()");
    public void OnGet() => Console.WriteLine("Divert.OnGet()");
}
```

And the following middleware:

```cs
public class TestMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("Divert"))
            context.Response.Redirect("/Divert");
        await _next(context);
    }
}

// Startup.cs:
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) 
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseMiddleware<TestMiddleware>();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapRazorPages());
}
```

As you can see, the middleware redirects every request to /Divert, except if the request goes to /Divert to avoid infinite redirects. When I start the server and try to go to /Index, I would expect to only see `Divert.ctor()` and `Divert.OnGet()` messages on the console because of the redirection, but for some reason, the original Index endpoint is still executed and rendered, because the messages `Index.ctor()` and `Index.OnGet()` are also printed.

From the browser's side, everything looks okay, /Index returns a 302 redirect code, and the browser then asks for /Divert. **Why is Index still executed and rendered on the server, and how can I avoid this?**

I have to call the _next delegate, because otherwise the request pipeline is broken, and nothing gets sent to the browser.

To add a bit of context, in my actual project, the middleware will check if a critical configuration file is present, and if it isn't, it redirects the user to a setup page where the file can be created. All the other pages (e.g. Index in this case) rely on this configuration, and they would throw and exception if it's missing.

Yes, I could add a safety check to every single page model class, but I'm hoping that there is a simpler solution that can prevent the original endpoint from being executed after a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, just had to call `context.Response.CompleteAsync()` in the middleware after the redirect.